# Redirecionar usuário para aplicativo do Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo um site site responsivo e usando a API do Google Maps para gerar o mapa de localização da empresa.

Gostaria de quando o usurário estivesse acessando o site por um dispositivo móvel e o mesmo clicasse sobre o mapa ou até mesmo um link, fosse redirecionado para o aplicativo do Google Maps e trassasse a rota, dessa forma ele não precisaria digitar o endereço e pesquisar.

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.0995734, -34.8410316);
 function initialize()
    {
      var mapProp = {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter,
            });
           marker.setMap(map);
        }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que este código resolveria seu problema:

```
javascript:window.open("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude+"" , "_system");
```

O mesmo oferece a opção nativa e a do google maps para o usuário, e caso queira que seja aberto no iOS:

```
 javascript:window.open("maps://maps.apple.com/?q=:"+latitude+","+longitude+"");
```

Você pode por exemplo criar uma  que recebe os valores em lat long caso seja dinâmico, mas pelo que vi seus dados são estáticos, então é mais simples, vá até seu html e insira este código de exemplo:

```
<div class="meuMapa"> 
  <a onclick="javascript:window.open('geo:-7.0995734, -34.8410316', '_system')> Clique aqui para abrir seu mapa
  </a>
</div>
```

Ou simplesmente você chama uma função em seu **onclick** onde a mesma verifica o tipo do device, por exemplo:

```
var devicePlatform = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";
if((devicePlatform == iPhone) || (devicePlatform == iPad))
{
   /*sua chamada de função*/
}
```

Comment: Marcos, da uma olhada na minha pergunta, eu acrescentei meu código, por favor veja onde eu posso colocar esta linha de código que você mencionou

Comment: editei a resposta @SérgioMachado da uma olhada ai

Comment: eu u sei o código, abria o mapa mas abria sem coordenadas, então fiz mais uma pesquisa na internet e achei a solução:
  $("#googleMap").on('click', function() {
            window.location = "http://maps.google.com/?q=Implantare+Soluções+em+Odontologia/";
        });

Comment: se funcionou ta tranquilo